# Create object from dynamic object

Tags: c#, dynamic

I have a JObject that contains json with the same structure as my Device class:

```
public class Entry
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public object value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
    }


    public class Device
    {
        public List<Detail> details { get; set; }
    }
```

I store the json as dynamic:

```
dynamic d = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
```

I want to create a device object from the dynamic object:

```
new Device { details = d.details }
```

I can't simply do like that because details is a list that contains a list, and the list has to be created with a constructor, i can't figure out how to do this. Should be something like?

```
new Device { details = new List<Detail> ( entry = new List<Entry>(some list from d?))}}
```

Please advice me.

EDIT:

The Json and my object does not share the same structure, it partly does, so i can't simply convert the while json.

Comment: Why not directly deserialize as an Entry ? Use   var entry = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Entry>(string json);

Comment: It's not exactly the same, it shares similarity, it's just this details property that i'm having issue with when creating my actual object.

It's almost 1000 properties in the objects so i can't post it all here.

Comment: Why are you using `dynamic`? Deserialize complete object whatever it is as a concrete type. If they both contains `List<Detail>` then simply assign value of one property to another property.

Answer (score 1):

If your JSON has exactly the same structure as `Device` class, then you should be able to just `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Device>(jsonString)`.

Even if the original JSON has some more properties, as long as your classes have the same property names, and what's an array's is an array etc. it should work.

Sample:

```
public class Entry
    {
        public string key { get; set; }
        public object value { get; set; }
    }

    public class Detail
    {
        public List<Entry> entry { get; set; }
    }


    public class Device
    {
        public List<Detail> details { get; set; }
    }

void Main()
{
    var json = @"
    {
      ""irrelevant"": ""fnord"",
      ""also_irrelevant"": [1,3,5,7],
      ""details"": [
       {
         ""not_entry"": true,
         ""entry"": [
           {
             ""key"": ""x"",
             ""value"": ""1""
           },
           {
             ""key"": ""y"",
             ""value"": ""2""
           }
         ]
       },
       {
         ""entry"": [
           {
             ""key"": ""a"",
             ""value"": ""3"",
             ""bummer"": ""hello""
           },
           {
             ""key"": ""b"",
             ""value"": ""4"",
             ""bummer"": ""hello""
           }
         ]
       }
      ]
    }";

    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Device>(json).Dump();
}
```

This runs nicely for me in LINQPad, showing resulting Device class with a list of Detail classes (2 entries), each with a list of Entry classes (2 entries each), with the kvp's set.

If you can, I'd go this route. If for some reason naming of the properties is off and you cannot change it, you can always use `[JsonProperty("actual_json_name")]` to override it.

Comment: It's not exactly the same, it shares similarity, it's just this details property that i'm having issue with when creating my actual object.

It's almost 1000 properties in the objects so i can't post it all here.